# Is there a way to get a fixed width of 100% in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my site more scalable, and would like all of my divs to take up the whole width of the page. If not, I would like them all to be centered and 960px. The problem is that none of the divs are actually centered when I try margin-left:auto, margin-right:auto;. When I try to make the width 100%, and then try to resize the window, everything gets wacky.

Here is the site:
http://eitanrosenberg.com/newsite/index.html

Here is my CSS:

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.everythang
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.topbar
{
    background-color:#000;
    height:75px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10;
}

.logo
{
    color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    font-family:HarabaraRegular,helvetica;
    font-size:45px;
    margin:15px auto 0 20px;
    padding-left:100px;
    position:relative;
    width:160px;
}

.navbar ul
{
    color:#FFF;
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-top:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navbar ul li
{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:15px auto 0 5px;
    padding-right:32px;
}

.navbar ul li a
{
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:HitchcockRegular, helvetica;
    font-size:25px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover
{
    color:#0CF;
}

.white
{
    background-color:#F8F8F8;
    background-image:url(gradients/radialg_200.png);
    background-position:30% 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:300px;
    margin:0;
    padding:50px 0 0;
    width:960px;
}

.hello
{
    color:red;
    font-family:CoolveticaRegular, helvetica;
    font-size:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:50px;
    text-align:center;
}

.hello2
{
    color:red;
    font-family:CoolveticaRegular, helvetica;
    font-size:35px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.hello3
{
    color:#0CF;
    font-family:CoolveticaRegular, helvetica;
    font-size:35px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.orange
{
    background-color:#F93;
    background-image:url(gradients/radialg_400.png);
    background-position:30% 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:500px;
    margin:0;
    padding:50px 0 0;
    width:960px;
}

.workbar ul
{
    color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    line-height:25px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-top:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.workbar ul li
{
    margin:2px auto 0 35px;
    padding-right:32px;
}

.workbar ul li a
{
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-size:25px;
    font-style:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.workbar ul li a:hover
{
    color:red;
}

.red
{
    background-color:red;
    background-image:url(gradients/radialg_400.png);
    background-position:30% 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:500px;
    margin:0;
    padding:50px 0 0;
    position:static;
    width:960px;
}

.red h2
{
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:45px;
    margin-left:100px;
    padding-top:40px;
}

.red ul
{
    color:#FFF;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-right:25px;
    margin-top:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.red ul li a
{
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-size:20px;
    font-style:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.faves img
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:15px;
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
}

.faves
{
    padding-top:25px;
}

.faves h2
{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-top:25px;
    padding-top:15px;
}

.lists
{
    margin-top:100px;
}

.list1
{
    float:left;
    width:320px;
}

.list2
{
    float:left;
    width:320px;
}

.list3
{
    width:320px;
}

.gray
{
    background-color:#2e3031;
    background-image:url(gradients/radialg_400.png);
    background-position:30% 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:700px;
    margin:0;
    padding:50px 0 0;
    position:static;
    width:960px;
}

.gray h2
{
    color:#FFF;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:45px;
    margin-left:100px;
    padding-top:40px;
}

.resumeImg img
{
    display:block;
    height:550px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:900px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Making an element centered using `margin` requires the element to have a layout. When using `margin-left` and `margin-right`, that would be the `width` property.

An alternate way to center your elements is :

```
position: absolute;
width: 800px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -400px;
```

You would move the element 50% from the left and then 400px (half the width) back. This also works for heights.

Comment: I guess I should say that I want to center my elements, but have a 100% top bar, that is 100% of the width and doesn't screw up when I try to resize the window, but thanks for the suggestion about the other elements!

Answer (score 0):

Have your wrapper `divs` ('white', 'orange', etc) be set to `width: 100%;` and have your content inside (preferably in another `div`, set to `width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;`:

```
.white, .orange {
  width: 100%;
} 

.white-wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And use the following HTML:

```
<div class="white">
  <div class="white-wrapper">
    -- content --
  </div>
</div>
```

In this way, your backgrounds will appropriately fill the page, and your content will float in the center and work correctly when shrinking the page. I'd recommend against dynamically changing the width of your content, as it presents readability issues (and tends to look gross), but if you really want to, try `min-width`:

```
.white {
  min-width: 960px;
}
```

This will ensure that your divs are always *at least* `960px` wide;

Comment: It got me to here: http://eitanrosenberg.com/newsite/index.html
Now, the colors aren't getting to 100% width. Should I try declaring the color in the .white,.red,.orange {} style?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. It is now very screwed up: http://eitanrosenberg.com/newsite/index.html

Comment: Well, since you removed the background styles completely from your stylesheets, it makes sense that there's no color showing up. You need to specify the background individually (i.e. .red { background: red; }

Comment: ok, that makes sense! Thanks! The only thing not working at all now is my header. I want it fixed, but it refuses to be cenetered AND fixed. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that's a whole different question, but you can use the method in the other answer to center your header correctly. However, using a fixed width header means if the window is less than 960px, you can't scroll to the right to see the whole menu. There are  javascript solutions to this - i.e. position absolute and setting the top position on scroll. (Also, remember to accept your answers :) )

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a fixed centered layout that is 960px wide UNLESS the browser window is less than 960px, then you want the layout to be full width.

To do this, wrap your entire html code in a container, like so:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <!-- your code here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

And apply this css:

```
#container {margin:0 auto;max-width:960px;}
```

Internet Explorer 6 doesn't understand max-width, so if that's a concern you could either give IE6 a fixed width of 960px:

```
#container {margin:0 auto;max-width:960px;}
* html #container {width:960px;} /* IE6 hack */
```

or force max-width in IE6 with an even uglier hack:

```
* html #container {width: expression(document.body.clientWidth > 962? "960px");
```